# Policy-Based Authorization to enable only Users who are owners to a resource be able to view/edit

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-3.0

I have a simple requirement of checking if a signed-in user is the owner of a resource before allowing the viewing/editing of the resource.
I have been able to accomplish this with checking in each ActionResult but would love to use the policy-based authorization to achieve this, documentation is silent on this particular requirement.

```
public IActionResult EditPage(int id)
{
   //Check User is the Owner of the resource
   var signedInUserResouceID = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("ResourceID");
   if(id != signedInUserResourceID)
   {
      //User cannot Edit this resouce
      return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
   }
   else
   {
      //Rightful owner, allow editing
   }
}
```

How do I use Policy-based authorization in achieving this

Comment: I found a way to remove passing a parameter altogether. But when I try it and it works will accept it if it does

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            //Here you can get many resouces from context, i get a claim here for example
            var yourvalue = context.User.FindFirst("ResourceID").Value;
            //here you can get the query string value
            var id = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext.Request.Query["id"];
            //return a boolen to end validation.
            return id==yourvalue;
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "EmployeeOnly")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult EditPage(int id)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me to solve the problem. this answer should be marked accepted

Answer (score 1):

Putting 'ResourceID' into user claims is not the way to achieve that.

Take a look at this article, it explains in details to to implement resource based authorization:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: The resource ID is permanent is even added to the AspNetUsersTable, it won't change. So I just need to compare that value which is an integer to the parameter id value.

Comment: Since the id param is dynamic, you would have to create your own policy that reads that value from the Http Request context param, if you wish to apply it with the `[Authorize(Policy = "YourCustomPolicy"]` attribute.