# Allow user only access his/her own resource with id in Authorize[] middleare .Net Core Api

Tags: asp.net, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, authorize-attribute

I am using role based authentication in .Net Core 3.1 Api. I am using Jwt tokens and user claims. Role based authentication works fine. But in some controllers I want to make sure that user gets his/her own data. Because if an employee sends other employee id in a request he/she can get that resource data, I don't want that.

I have email, id and roles in token with some other data.

What I want is that something like [Authorize(Roles="Employee", Id={userId})]

```
[HttpGet("getUserInventory")]
    //[Authorize(Roles="Employee", Claims.Id={userId})]
    public IActionResult getUserInventory([FromQuery] int userId)
    {
        var inventories = _userInventoryExportService.GetGlobalInventory(userId);
        if(inventories.Success)
        {
            return Ok(inventories.Data);
        }
        return BadRequest(inventories.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Emre, did you consider using policy-based authentication like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723006/11398810)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial we've created at Curity: [Securing a .NET Core API](https://curity.io/resources/learn/dotnet-api/). You will see there how to configure authorization based on claims found in a JWT access token.

Answer (score 0):

had the same use case, to authorize user access to its own mailbox only.

controller:

```
[HttpPost("{address}/inbox/messages/list")]
[Authorize(Policy = "userAddress")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> ListMessages([FromRoute] string address)
    {
        // return user mailbox data.
    }
```

here i define the `userAddress`, and also the way i pull the `address` string from the url. it is not possible to pass this value from the controller, i had to pick it from a global request class:

```
//Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("userAddress", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            var userAddress = context.User.FindFirst(JWTClaim.Email).Value;
            // /api/v1/mailbox/email@example.com/inbox/messages/list
            var address = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["address"].ToString(); 
            return address == userAddress;
        });
    });
});
```

it is worth to note that the `context` contains the actual request values, but is not publicly accessible, only via debugger:

```
context.Resource.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["address"].ToString();
```

Comment: what if im using request body instead and i need to check OrderId (user has List<Order> on it)? is it better to add claim with available OrderIds to token?

Comment: @vilemcech im not exactly sure what do you mean. but passing existing order ids into token claims isnt a sustainable idea in general.

Comment: i ended up with putting orderId into query instead of body so it was more accessible. i think ive seen example of passing list of ids into token in deunde identity server docs. if the list is finite it could work but it would have been tidious...